# Creating a simple shell in C causes linking error

Tags: c, shell

I am creating a simple shell in C that can execute commands, do stdout redirects and piping. So far I got only the redirecting part done but for some reason when i try to compile collect2 throws an error.

The util.c file that I am including:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include"util.h"


void setSigHandler(){
    void (*oldHandler)();

    oldHandler = signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTERM, oldHandler);
}

void prompt(){
    char* user = getlogin();
    printf("[%s]-->$", user);
}

void getNextCommand(){
    errno = 0;
    cmd = malloc(sizeof *cmd);
    if(cmd == NULL){
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        printf("malloc:%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fgets(cmd->payload, sizeof(cmd->payload), stdin);

    if(cmd->payload[strlen(cmd->payload) - 1] == '\n'){
        cmd->payload[strlen(cmd->payload) - 1] = '\0';
    }
}

void parseCommandString(){
    cmd->payloadArgc = 0;
    char* buffer = strtok(cmd->payload, " ");
    while(buffer != NULL){
        cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc] = buffer;
        if(!strcmp(cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc], ">")){
            cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc] = NULL;
            fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");
            break;
        }
        if(!strcmp(cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc], "|")){
            cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc] = NULL;
            pCount++;
            break;
        }
        buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");    
        cmd->payloadArgc++;
    }
}
```

And my main file :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/file.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include"util.h"

int execCommand();

int main(){
    setSigHandler();

    while(1){
        prompt();
        getNextCommand();

        //pdsh exits on "close"
        if(!strcmp(cmd->payloadArgv[0], "close")) break;

        parseCommandString();

    }

    return 0;
}

int execCommand()
{
    errno = 0;
    int newFd;

    // Fork process
    pid_t pid = fork();

    // Error
    if (pid == -1) {
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        printf("fork: %s\n", error);
        return -1;
    }

    // Child process
    else if (pid == 0) {
        if(fileName != NULL){
            newFd = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0755);
            if(newFd == -1){
                char* error = strerror(errno);
                printf("open: %s\n", error);
                return -2;
            }
            dup2(newFd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(newFd);
        }

        // Execute command
        execvp(cmd->payloadArgv[0], cmd->payloadArgv);  

        // Error occurred
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        printf("shell: %s: %s\n", cmd->payloadArgv[0], error);
        return -2;
    }

    // Parent process
    else {
        close(newFd);
        fileName = NULL;

        // Wait for child process to finish
        int childStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childStatus, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And the error from collect2:

```
/tmp/ccIXS72e.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `fileName'
/tmp/ccINCcwP.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccIXS72e.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `pCount'
/tmp/ccINCcwP.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccIXS72e.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `newDescriptor'
/tmp/ccINCcwP.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is causing this?

I know my main.c code is a little ugly sorry for that.

**Edit**: The util.h as requested:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE !TRUE
#define STDOUT 0
#define STDIN 1
#define MAX_CMD_LENGHT 500
#define MAX_CMD_ARGS_LENGHT 50

char* fileName = NULL;
int pCount = -1;
int newDescriptor = -1;

Command cmd;


typedef struct commandR* Command;
struct commandR{
    char payload[MAX_CMD_LENGHT];
    char* payloadArgv[MAX_CMD_ARGS_LENGHT];
    int payloadArgc;
};

void setSigHandler();

void prompt();

void getNextCommand();

void parseCommand();


#endif
```

**Edit 2**: After a suggestion I have modified my code. Error still goes off.

util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE !TRUE
#define STDOUT 0
#define STDIN 1
#define MAX_CMD_LENGHT 500
#define MAX_CMD_ARGS_LENGHT 50

extern int newDescriptor;
extern char* fileName;
extern int pCount;


typedef struct commandR* Command;
struct commandR{
    char payload[MAX_CMD_LENGHT];
    char* payloadArgv[MAX_CMD_ARGS_LENGHT];
    int payloadArgc;
};

extern Command cmd;

void setSigHandler();

void prompt();

void getNextCommand();

void parseCommand();


#endif
```

util.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include"util.h"


char* fileName = NULL;
int pCount = -1;
int newDescriptor = -1;
Command cmd;

void setSigHandler(){
    void (*oldHandler)();

    oldHandler = signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTERM, oldHandler);
}

void prompt(){
    char* user = getlogin();
    printf("[%s]-->$", user);
}

void getNextCommand(){
    errno = 0;
    cmd = malloc(sizeof *cmd);
    if(cmd == NULL){
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        printf("malloc:%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fgets(cmd->payload, sizeof(cmd->payload), stdin);

    if(cmd->payload[strlen(cmd->payload) - 1] == '\n'){
        cmd->payload[strlen(cmd->payload) - 1] = '\0';
    }
}

void parseCommandString(){
    cmd->payloadArgc = 0;
    char* buffer = strtok(cmd->payload, " ");
    while(buffer != NULL){
        cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc] = buffer;
        if(!strcmp(cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc], ">")){
            cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc] = NULL;
            fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");
            break;
        }
        if(!strcmp(cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc], "|")){
            cmd->payloadArgv[cmd->payloadArgc] = NULL;
            pCount++;
            break;
        }
        buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");    
        cmd->payloadArgc++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your util.h. I have suspicion.

Comment: I suspect you got global variable in the util.h that should be in the util.c, and "extern var_type var_name" in the .h is missing

Comment: Yes those variables that it reports are global. They should be in the util.c file? Didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have variables defined in the header file.  So when you compile each .c file, they both contain a copy of those variables.  This causes the linker error of multiple definitions.

What you need to do is *declare* them in the header file with the `extern` keyword.  That allows the variables to be used without being defined.  Then you define them in exactly one .c file.

util.h:

```
extern char* fileName;
extern int pCount;
extern int newDescriptor;
extern Command cmd;
```

util.c:

```
char* fileName = NULL;
int pCount = -1;
int newDescriptor = -1;
Command cmd;
```

Also note that the variables are initialized where they are defined, not where they are declared.

EDIT:

It looks like the problem is how you're compiling.  You need to compile `main.c` and `util.c` to object files, then link the resulting object files:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c main.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c util.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o main main.o util.o
```

Also, you need to put the declaration of `parseCommandString` into `util.h`, and you need to include `sys/types.h` and `sys/wait.h` in `main.c` for `waitpid`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Never worked with global variables from a header before. Do I need to do this for the Command variable too? If not why is this?

Comment: @Akaitenshi Yes, you need to do it for that as well.  On a side note, it's generally bad practice to `typedef` a pointer.  It hides the fact that a pointer is being used and can lead to confusion.

Comment: I know that, it's a bad habit that university has stuck to me. On the topic: I did the change but I still get the same error

Comment: @Akaitenshi Is it complaining about the same variables or something else?

Comment: @Akaitenshi Then update your question with the updated code (but leave the original code).

Comment: @Akaitenshi, your header must not only declare the variables `extern`, it must *avoid* providing initializers for them.  Additionally, exactly *one* C file should provide the definitions of these variables.  Or, much better, avoid relying on global variables altogether.

Comment: I think compiling the sources separately and linking them afterward is a false trail.  If the multiple-definition problem is correctly resolved then it will not matter whether the sources are compiled together or separately.